# Use customer table for role based access control instead of user in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, rbac, yii2-rbac

I want to use table login_info instead of table user in yii2 to create member activities in frontend part that are not in the backend part. Also I have roles at the table login_info like :health-post, hospital, fchv, etc, not can be managed from user_id but can manage from user_name . Do you have in any idea in yii2.

Answer (score 0):

If  you want change only the tablename  (and the schema of the table is like the yii user table ) you can easily (re)define the function tableName  in your

frontend\models   User.php  eg: this way

```
namespace frontend\models;

use yii\models\web\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return  'yuor_table_user';
    }
}
```

But if you want define a your User component based on your specific features you should create a new proper User  class that implement the Identity interface 
You can see the the [authentication - security guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html) , [the user interface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-identityinterface.html)  and the [yii user class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) for reference and sample

Is not a simple job.